# Level DEM from ArcHydro Tools 0x80040202 error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arc-hydro

When I tried to run Level DEM tool from the ArcHydro Tools, it returns me an error message:

Level DEM System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040202): The index passed was not within the valid range.
[image]

App versions:
ArcGIS Desktop: 10.5
ArcHydro Tools: 10.5.0.221

- DEM is in the ESRI grid format (raster is inside a folder); the DEM's values are in meters (float) but I tried change it to cm (int). In the `DEM_cm` raster I have changed in the `prj.adf` file `Zunits` value to 100 - without any progress.
- lakes polygon feature class (inside geodatabase)

DEM in Projected Coordinate System (WKID: 2180).

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have change the ArcGIS to the newest 10.8 ver. and the newest Arc Hydro tools but the situation didn't improve.
The problem was solved by assigning the `HydroID` attribute for the lakes feature class.